# Looping String arrays : cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to java and I'm banging my head against a wall with a task. I need to get this to work. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?  I need to write an application for Carl’s Carpentry that shows a user a list of available items: table, desk, dresser, or entertainment center. Allow the user to enter a string that corresponds to one of the options, and display the price as $250, $325, $420, or $600, accordingly. Display an error message if the user enters an invalid item. The program MUST contain parallel arrays.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class CarpentryChoice
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String entry;
        String [] item = {"table","desk","dresser","entertainment center"};
        int [] price = {250, 325, 420, 600};
        String strPiece;
        int x, fi = 99;
        String prompt = "Please select an item\n" +
        "Our furniture is:\n" + "Table\n" +
        "Desk\n" +
        "Dresser\n" +
        "Entertainment center\n" +
        "Enter an item letter";
        entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
        entry = strPiece.ToString();
            for(x = 0; x < item.length; ++x)
            if(strPiece == item[x])
                fi = x;
                if(fi == 99)
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Invalid item code entered");
                else
                {
                    if (fi > 2)
                        fi = fi - 3;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Furniture item " +
                        strPiece + " is priced at $" +
                        price[fi]);
                }
                System.exit(0);
    } 
}
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: Typo: `strPiece.ToString()` should be `strPiece.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

1. It is `toString` instead of `ToString`.
2. Why are you assigning `entry` twice? The second assignment will override what the user input via the prompt dialog. You don't need the variable `strPiece` in this case. You can just use `entry`:

   ```
   entry = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);            
       for(x = 0; x < item.length; ++x)
   ```
3. To compare `String`s, use the [`equals` instead of the `==` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java):

   `if(entry.equals(item[x]))`

And in the part that displays the result dialog, use `entry` again instead of `strPiece` (simply remove `strPiece` from the entire code):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Furniture item " +
                    entry + " is priced at $" +
                    price[fi]);
```

Comment: You could add, that his code misses a lot of braces (`{`, `}`). `The second assignment will override` ... more likely will it throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Tom I may be wrong, but I think it is just incorrect indenting.

Comment: @StephenB .. maybe. Let's hope so.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I made the changes and now I'm getting a weird output. It says "Furniture item [Ljava.lang.string;@5ce65a89 is priced at $250". The characters after the ampersand are always different. The price is correct, but, obviously the Ljava part is not. What did I do incorrectly here?

Comment: @haldav updated the answer. I think it's related to the last part where you display the result.

Comment: Interestingly enough, manouti, right after I posted my reply, I saw the change I needed to make on my own and when came back to post an update you had already posted. That's EXACTLY what I did to fix it. Thanks a bunch! It's always the obvious things!